# Overleaf V2 - How to get BBL File?

Tags: overleaf

Overleaf V2 does not seem to have a way to get the BBL file for arxiv, how do I get it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can get the `bbl` file if you click on the "log and other files" icon next to compile, recompile icon just above the pdf viewer. Then you can scroll down, and at the bottom you have a "log and other file" icon/button, you can select it to download the `bbl` file. [image]

Comment: Another method is to click on "Submit" and then choose e.g. "arXiv", there will be an option to download a .zip with the .bbl included. Once you click the button, it should show a "Please wait" message and take a while to build the zip. Then the button comes back, only this time it is a download link that will immediately download the zip archive.

Comment: I tried @imnothere's method but the generated zip file did not contain the `bbl` file. I could get it with @Guido's method though.

Answer (score 17):

*(Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.)*

Click on "Submit" and then choose e.g. "arXiv", there will be an option to download a `.zip` with the `.bbl` included. Once you click the button, it should show a "Please wait" message and take a while to build the zip. Then the button comes back, only this time it is a download link that will immediately download the zip archive.

Comment: I tried this but the generated zip file did not contain the bbl file. I wonder if I missed something obvious.

Comment: Same issue for me. @imnothere are you able to confirm what might cause this?

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer of @imnothere you have to name the bib and text file identically and then follow the answer provided by @imnothere. It worked for me alright.