# Biblatex prints reference keys instead of author names and year

Tags: biblatex

I'm having trouble implementing my citations in my Latex document on overleaf. I'm using the following preamble-options:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    man,
    british
]{apa6}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\clubpenalty=10000 
\widowpenalty=10000
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=black,filecolor=black, urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% for back reference in bibliography
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}

% maps apacite commands to biblatex commands
\let \citeNP \cite
\let \citeA \textcite
\let \cite \parencite

%%%
% Apa Bib - enable reprint according to apa
%%%

\input{enable-reprint}
\raggedbottom
\bibliography{./ref}
```

I uploaded a ref.bib file containing all my bibliography-information. I can also access the various objects of my ref.bib file by using the \cite{Green.2016} call. However, in the pdf it does print the reference key "Green.2016" instead of the authors name and year.
I would really appreciate any hints on how to solve the problem.

---

[Screenshot of Input and logs/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEzWS.png)

Comment: `\addbibressource{ref.bib}` seems to be missing in your code

Comment: You are loading quite a number of packages in your preamble. Do you need all of them? Do you know what each package does (at least roughly)?

Comment: Copying my comments from under the now deleted post in the answer section: Screenshots of code and log files are always a bit tricky to work with. And the digest of the error messages provided by Overleaf does not show everything that is relevant. Please turn your code in the question into a compilable example document with `\begin{document}...\end{document}` etc.(https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and post the *complete* `.log` and `.blg` files (you can upload the `.log` to a text-sharing website such as http://pastebin.com, since it will likely be too long for the question).

Comment: ... See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864 for details on how to obtain the `.log` and `.blg` file (the post shows it for the `.bbl` file, but the method is the same).

Answer (score 1):

The `apa6` documentclass has a special option to enable `biblatex`, use this option instead of loading the package yourself.

With biblatex you should use `\printbibliography` instead of `\bibliography{...}`

Unrelated to the bibliograpy, but `\shorttitle{...}` was missing in your document and you should not load the same package more than once

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    man,
    british,
    biblatex
]{apa6}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\clubpenalty=10000 
\widowpenalty=10000
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=black,filecolor=black, urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% for back reference in bibliography
%\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}

% maps apacite commands to biblatex commands
\let \citeNP \cite
\let \citeA \textcite
\let \cite \parencite

\title{text}
\shorttitle{dd}
\begin{document}
\cite{knuth}

%%%
% Apa Bib - enable reprint according to apa
%%%

%\input{enable-reprint}
\raggedbottom
%\bibliography{./ref}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

---

For the special case of the ancient texlive version of overleaf, the following should work:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    man,
    british,
    biblatex,
]{apa6}

%\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\clubpenalty=10000 
\widowpenalty=10000
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=black,filecolor=black, urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% for back reference in bibliography
%\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}


% maps apacite commands to biblatex commands
\let \citeNP \cite
\let \citeA \textcite
\let \cite \parencite

\title{text}
\shorttitle{dd}
\begin{document}
\cite{1992JEEEA..12..103F}

%%%
% Apa Bib - enable reprint according to apa
%%%

%\input{enable-reprint}
\raggedbottom
%\bibliography{./ref}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(https://www.overleaf.com/read/qwqgydyqfjyr)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately, using the biblatex-option in the documentclass specification and deleting the load of the package itself does not solve the Problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Jan Can you add a link to your overleaf project?

Comment: @Jan Did you also replace `\bibliography`?

Comment: @Jan Argggg, overleaf seems to have an ancient version of biblatex

Comment: @Jan Best course of action: write to overleaf support and complain about their outdated texlive installation. maybe they will finally update if enough user complain

Comment: @Jan This seems to work: https://www.overleaf.com/read/qwqgydyqfjyr

Comment: I copied your preamble into my Project. Yet, it doesn't work. I have no clue what I'm missing...

Comment: @Jan Try the other way round. Create a new project with the code from my answer, test if it works, if yes copy the document body from your document there

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work either. Above, I posted a screenshot of my Input and the log, maybe that helps. How can I re-run Biber on overleaf?

Comment: @Jan Can you show the .bib entry you try to cite?

Comment: This is the entry:

@article{Jackson.2001,
 author = {Jackson, Melanie and Tisak, Marie S.},
 year = {2001},
 title = {Is prosocial behaviour a good thing Developmental changes in children's evaluations of helping, sharing, cooperating, and comforting},
 pages = {349--367},
 volume = {19},
 journal = {British Journal of Developmental Psychology}
}