# empty bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

My preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
%\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,mathrsfs,enumerate}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{artemisia}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\textcolor{black}{$\blacksquare$}}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{thmtools}

\useshorthands{;}
\defineshorthand{;}{?}


\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibl.bib}
```

then  before the `\end{document}` I wrote

```
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
```

but nothing appears (the bibliography does not appear) and I get an error "empty bibliography on imput line 616".

Any help?

[image]

Maybe this helps

[image]

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.12
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'output.blg'
[43] biber:315> INFO - === Sat Oct 19, 2019, 07:04:29
[75] Biber.pm:371> INFO - Reading 'output.bcf'
[180] Biber.pm:886> INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
[204] Biber.pm:4093> INFO - Processing section 0
[217] Biber.pm:4254> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'bibl.bib' for section 0
[219] bibtex.pm:1523> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[229] bibtex.pm:1340> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bibl.bib'
[255] bibtex.pm:94> FATAL - Caught signal: SEGV
Likely your .bib has a very bad entry which causes libbtparse to crash: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Did you run Biber? You need to compile your document with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where LaTeX can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for a more in depth explanation. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help in getting your editor to run Biber for you.

Comment: @moewe Thank you! I write it online in overleaf. Do you know where I can see the compiler I use?

Comment: Overleaf automatically runs Biber for you. In that case there must be an error somewhere. Download the **`.blg`** file (shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864 for the `.bbl`) and post its complete contents here.

Comment: When I open the file it seems empty, how can I post it here?

Comment: It's a text file, even if Windows says it is a performance monitor file. Just open it with your favourite text editor.

Comment: Did I upload it right?

Comment: Yup. The error does not look good and isn't particularly helpful. There must be something seriously wrong with your `.bib` file (my guess is an `author` field). Can you share your `.bib` file with us?

Comment: I did so (I write in greek so I use \textlatin)

Comment: @moewe Thank you again. I found it. If you want write something as an answer to give you some points.

Comment: Er, so what was the answer?

Comment: In the bibliograpfy file I had to write the shortnames of the books with the first letter capital

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but if you found the solution, please consider writing an answer below and accepting it so that other people can benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem (via Overleaf).
As a background, I migrated my bibliography from natbib to biblatex with the reference items over 300.
As far as I understand, biblatex in Overleaf uses biber as a default?

Then I tried to use bibtex as its backend

\usepackage**[backend=bibtex]**{biblatex}, and magically it works!

Hope this helps.