# Bibliography entries are available to \cite but are undefined when complied

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, mendeley

I'm very new to Overleaf, and I've really tried to find an answer to this but they are either not relevant or I have failed to understand.
I have exported my references from Mendeley (NOT via the integration service (I'm not premium)) in BibTex format.

I have saved these as "bibliography.bib"

I have this in the preamble

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

and at just before the end of the document

```
\printbibliography
```

I then get no bibliography printed, and many

"You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way."

errors that I don't understand, as they are all there, and will even autofill with \cite

I also get an error

"Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: output and rerun LaTeX afterwards."

How do I run biber on the file?

I'm incredibly lost and as this point I think I've sunk like two hours trying to fix this so I'm REALLY hoping someone can help.

I have included my entire preamble below just in case you guys can spot something a noob like me missed. - I have also included an example of one of the bibliography entries that fail to be read.

Thank you for your help :)

---

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}


\title{Title of Project}
\author{Authornames}
\date{THE DATE}



\begin{document}
```

---

(there are no gaps between the fields in the actual bib, stackexchange is either putting it on the same line or with a gap between it, idk how to change that)

```
@article{Chow,

abstract = {The generation of amyloid $\beta$-peptide (A$\beta$) by enzymatic cleavages of the $\beta$-amyloid precursor protein (APP) has been at the center of Alzheimer's disease (AD) research. While the basic process of $\beta$-and $\gamma$-secretase-mediated generation of A$\beta$ is text book knowledge, new aspects of A$\beta$ and other cleavage products have emerged in recent years. Also our understanding of the enzymes involved in APP proteolysis has increased dramatically. All of these discoveries contribute to a more complete understanding of APP processing and the physiological and pathological roles of its secreted and intracellular protein products. Understanding APP processing is important for any therapeutic strategy aimed at reducing A$\beta$ levels in AD. In this review we provide a concise description of the current state of understanding the enzymes involved in APP processing, the cleavage products generated by different processing patterns, and the potential functions of those cleavage products.},

author = {Chow, Vivian W and Mattson, Mark P and Wong, Philip C and Gleichmann, Marc},

doi = {10.1007/s12017-009-8104-z},

file = {:home/barny/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Chow et al. - Unknown - An Overview of APP Processing Enzymes and Products(2).pdf:pdf},

keywords = {AICD,APP,Amyloid beta,$\alpha$-secretase,$\beta$-secretase,$\gamma$-secretase},

title = {{An Overview of APP Processing Enzymes and Products}}

}
```

---

Comment: Welcome. Are you using a tool to run LaTeX like TexStudio, TexLive?

Comment: Thank you :) but I have never heard of those so I assume not, I'm using it in Overleaf

Comment: The fact that nothing appears seems to a symptom of you not using biber as the backend, i.e. your question is essentially: `How do I use biber?`. Therefore, maybe the answers here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26516/118712 may help you.

Comment: Since you are using Overleaf you don't have to worry about running Biber. Overleaf uses the tool `latexmk` that automatically runs Biber for you. So your problem lies elsewhere. It can be down to roughly two things: (1) Your document errors so badly on the LaTeX run so that subsequent Biber runs are impossible. (2) The Biber run errors so badly that it does not produce usable output. Check for the first possibility first. If there is a little number in red next to the recompile button you have errors. Resolve them one by one starting from the first error. ...

Comment: ... If there are no more LaTeX errors, check for Biber errors. For this we need the `.blg` file. That file needs to be downloaded manually. The procedure is described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864 for the `.bbl` file. You can go through the same steps to get the **`.blg`** file. The `.blg` file is a simple text file (no matter what your system might say), you can open it with any text editor and it is small enough that it can be uploaded in the question here.

Comment: If you want a simple test document to see how things work try https://gist.github.com/moewew/4e0580ae8832da44127b2a45aec02e35 (you do not need to change anything about that document, the file `biblatex-examples.bib` uses there is available on all systems with `biblatex` and will be found automatically).

Answer (score 1):

I tried your MWE. Try citing the bib entry as `\cite{Chow}`.

As you have probably noticed, Overleaf pops up a suggestion menu with the relevant bibliography entries you have in your `addbibresource`.

The string to be provided to `cite{}` is the first string inside the curly brackets of the bibliography entry, generated by Mendeley. `Chow` in your example.

Just to make it clearer, as another example, for this bibliography entry:

```
@article{Einstein1905,
    author = "Albert Einstein",
    title = "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal = "Annalen der Physik",
    volume = "322",
    number = "10",
    pages = "891--921",
    year = "1905",
}
```

You should use `\cite{Einstein1905}`.

I hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. Only to help in the debugging.

Try this code. It should run twice + biber+ other two compilation, ending with no errors. You should get the output of the figure.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myreferences.bib}
    @book{yang2018optimization,
        title={Optimization Techniques and Applications with Examples},
        author={Yang, Xin-She},
        year={2018},
        publisher={John Wiley~\& Sons},
    }

@article{Chow,  
    abstract = {The generation of amyloid $\beta$-peptide (A$\beta$) by enzymatic cleavages of the $\beta$-amyloid precursor protein (APP) has been at the center of Alzheimer's disease (AD) research. While the basic process of $\beta$-and $\gamma$-secretase-mediated generation of A$\beta$ is text book knowledge, new aspects of A$\beta$ and other cleavage products have emerged in recent years. Also our understanding of the enzymes involved in APP proteolysis has increased dramatically. All of these discoveries contribute to a more complete understanding of APP processing and the physiological and pathological roles of its secreted and intracellular protein products. Understanding APP processing is important for any therapeutic strategy aimed at reducing A$\beta$ levels in AD. In this review we provide a concise description of the current state of understanding the enzymes involved in APP processing, the cleavage products generated by different processing patterns, and the potential functions of those cleavage products.}, 
    author = {Chow, Vivian W and Mattson, Mark P and Wong, Philip C and Gleichmann, Marc},  
    doi = {10.1007/s12017-009-8104-z},
    file = {:home/barny/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Chow et al. - Unknown - An Overview of APP Processing Enzymes and Products(2).pdf:pdf}, 
    keywords = {AICD,APP,Amyloid beta,$\alpha$-secretase,$\beta$-secretase,$\gamma$-secretase}, 
    title = {{An Overview of APP Processing Enzymes and Products}}  
}

 \end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}   

\title{Title of Project}
\author{Authornames}
\date{THE DATE}


\begin{document}
    
See \cite{yang2018optimization} an also \cite{Chow}.

\printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

[image: c]

As you can see the Chow reference needs to be completed.

Comment: From my experience with Overleaf, sometimes it is quicker to [Clear the cache](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache), instead of compiling the document a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this 2 days ago, the reason was for my problem is that in my main.tex file i did not write the right path to my litrature.bib . I also use overleaf. I do hope this would help you