# Some citations becomes citation label instead of of number reference

Tags: errors, citing, biber, labels, overleaf

When citing my sources, most citations works like intended (i.e., `...[1]`). However, a few have become brackets with the citation label inside **`[citation-label]`**. In those cases, the source does not appear in the reference list. However, there are no errors, so I struggle to find out what is wrong.

This is my code:

```
% --- Bibliography & References---  
\usepackage[backend = biber,% Recommended backend for sorting bibliography
            style = numeric,
            urldate = long,  
            maxcitenames = 1, 
            sorting = none,
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}   

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\vspace{-4pt} \caption*{\hfill \footnotesize{Source: {#1}} } }
```

```
% Printing bibliography
\newpage
\printbibliography[heading = bibintoc, title = Bibliography]
```

These are some examples of the sources not working:

```
@article{dorsalstream,
    author= "Peter C. Hansen, John F. Stein, Sam R. Orde, Jonathan L. Winter and Joel B. Talcott",
    title = "Are dyslexics' visual deficits limited to measures of dorsal stream function?",
    journal = "Neuroreport",
    volume = "12",
    number = "7",
    year = "2001",
}

@article{genetics,
    author = "Johannes Schumacher, Per Hoffmann, Christine Schmäl, Gerd Schulte-Kö̈rne, Markus M. Nöthen",
    title = "Genetics of dyslexia: the evolving landscape",
    journal = "Journal of Medical Genetics",
    volume = "44",
    pages = "289-297",
    year = "2007",
    DOI = "10.1136/jmg.2006.046516",
}

@article{fmri,
    author = "Guinevere F. Eden, John W. VanMeter, Judith M. Rumsey, José Ma. Maisog, Roger P. Woods and Thomas A. Zeffiro",
    title = "Abnormal processing of visual motion in dyslexia revealed by functional brain imaging",
    journal = "Nature",
    volume = "382",
    pages = "66-69",
    year = "1996",
    DOI = "https://doi.org/10.1038/382066a0",
}
```

Most of the above examples do not appear after each other in the document, but in between other functioning sources.

This is how it appears in the text:

[image]

I am using overleaf with pdfLaTex compiler.

Comment: After adding the `\cite` commands, did you run a full latex-biber-latex recompile cycle?

Comment: If only some of your references don't resolve (i.e. show in bold and throw a warning) and you did run Biber (which happens automatically on Overleaf) the most likely explanation is an error in the relevant `.bib` entries themselves. These errors are not reported by LaTeX, they are reported by Biber. On Overleaf the best way to get hold of these errors is by downloading the `.blg` file (as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864 for the `.bbl` file). ...

Comment: ... In your case the `.blg` file should tell you that the name lists in the entries are malformed, they contain too many commas. Regardless of the desired output *all* names must be separated by `and`. So `author= "Peter C. Hansen, John F. Stein, Sam R. Orde, Jonathan L. Winter and Joel B. Talcott",` must be `author= "Peter C. Hansen amd John F. Stein and Sam R. Orde and Jonathan L. Winter and Joel B. Talcott",` and similarly for the other entries. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864.

Comment: I just had a look at the Overleaf interface and you should be able to see the relevant errors even without downloading the `.blg` file. The little icon left of the "Recompile" button should show a number on a red background. Click on that icon and scroll down to the red error messages (ignore the orange warnings for now), those messages should tell you about the wrong commas in the relevant `.bib` entries. Fix all errors and recompile

Comment: Not relevant to the question at hand, but should still be addressed: `Gerd Schulte-Kö̈rne` in `genetics` looks wrong (there is an `ö` with additional dots above) and should probably just be `Gerd Schulte-Körne` (with just a normal `ö`). Finally, the `doi` field should contain just the DOI and not the `http(s)` bit, so `fmri`'s `DOI = "https://doi.org/10.1038/382066a0",` should be `DOI = "10.1038/382066a0",`.

Comment: Hi, Tom from Overleaf Support here As @moewe pointed out, these seem like malformed bibliography entries. Note that Overleaf's log parser should catch this and warn you about them by a red number next to the Recompile button; clicking on the number should show you a list of the errors. Note that bibliography errors are by the bottom of the list so it might be necessary to scroll down.