# Why are some of the citations not showing up in text? and replaced by a question mark

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, ieeetran

I'm writing a paper for the HRI 2022 conference. I uploaded all my references in a .bib file. I cite them with `\cite` in the main text but *some* citations are not classified by numbers but with a question mark?

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2020)
Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003
The top-level auxiliary file: output.aux
The style file: IEEEtran.bst
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated wiz_functions (elt_size=4) to 6000 items from 3000.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Database file #1: REFBIB.bib
Repeated entry---line 165 of file REFBIB.bib
 : @inproceedings{erel2021excluded
 :                                ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 259 of file REFBIB.bib
 : @article{williams2009ostracism
 :                               ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 269 of file REFBIB.bib
 : @article{maner2010endocrinology
 :                                ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 290 of file REFBIB.bib
 : @article{leiro2014prosocial
 :                            ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 488 of file REFBIB.bib
 : @article{williams2009ostracism
 :                               ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 505 of file REFBIB.bib
 : @article{williams2007ostracism
 :                               ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Illegal end of database file---line 1588 of file REFBIB.bib
 : 
 : 
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "lakin2005exclusion"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "baumeister1990point"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "riva2014orders"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "gillath2008can"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "thomas1995illusion"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "faul2007g"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "caprara2005new"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "candini2021physiological"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "sommer1959studies"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "teneggi2012social"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "burgoon1976toward"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "cook1970experiments"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "deutsch1975behavioral"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "argyle1965eye"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "sommer1969personal"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "riem2019oxytocin"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "roberts1997children"
-- IEEEtran.bst version 1.12 (2007/01/11) by Michael Shell.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/
-- See the "IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf" manual for usage information.
Warning--empty journal in wortham2016does
Warning--empty journal in williams2001ostracism
Warning--empty journal in crick1999childhood
Warning--empty journal in pickett2005social
Warning--empty journal in batson2003altruism
Warning--empty year in lovejasp

Done.
You've used 78 entries,
            4024 wiz_defined-function locations,
            1248 strings with 23779 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 61315 in all, are:
= -- 4967
> -- 1571
< -- 537
+ -- 843
- -- 275
* -- 2923
:= -- 9035
add.period$ -- 167
call.type$ -- 78
change.case$ -- 74
chr.to.int$ -- 1215
cite$ -- 84
duplicate$ -- 4402
empty$ -- 4888
format.name$ -- 341
if$ -- 14203
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 78
missing$ -- 765
newline$ -- 259
num.names$ -- 78
pop$ -- 1778
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 2
skip$ -- 4789
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 2951
swap$ -- 3632
text.length$ -- 132
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 5
type$ -- 78
warning$ -- 6
while$ -- 308
width$ -- 80
write$ -- 770
(There were 7 error messages)
```

Comment: ? is the expected output on the first run, if running bibtex then latex again doesn't resolve it there should be an error message in the bibtex or latex log saying what the problem is,

Comment: you tagged this biblatex but if you get ? most likely you are using bibtex (as biblatex normally shows the `cite` key argument for unknown references)

Comment: Overleaf should automatically run BibTeX for you. And it usually does so very reliably provided there are no errors in your LaTeX file. Before you do anything else, check that there are no errors reported. If there are errors, resolve them from top to bottom. You can only expect proper output if there are no errors. If LaTeX does not report errors and you still don't get all citations, clear the cache: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache. ...

Comment: ... If you still don't get the expected output, chances are there is an issue with your `.bib` file. Issues like this will usually be logged in the `.blg` file (BibTeX's log). Download the file as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864 (but download the `.blg`, not the `.bbl`), then open it (since it is a text file, any text editor will do) and check it for helpful hints.

Comment: If after following the other great advice in these comments you are still having problems, please get in touch with Overleaf support (support@overleaf.com) and we can offer some further suggestions (I'm on the support team).

Comment: I'm very much confused about what I should do because for some references it's working properly but for others not

Comment: There are two main explanations as to why some references work and others not: (1) Only references added a while ago work, newly added references do not work. Usually this is associated with BibTeX not running or refusing to complete running. This can be caused by LaTeX errors that stop `latexmk` from running BibTeX for you or by really bad BibTeX errors. Overleaf's interface will show you about LaTeX errors. You can find out about BibTeX errors in the `.blg` file (see my comment above). ...

Comment: ... (2) Some entries work, some don't, but there is no correlation with when these entries were added to the `.bib` file. In that case the most likely explanation is that those entries that don't work are faulty. BibTeX will tell you about faulty entries in the `.blg` file.

Comment: Yes this is the case I copy pasted references from a previous overleaf document and added new references

Comment: but overleafs interface does not show me the errors

Comment: Overleaf's error messages can be a bit ... inconspicuous: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7898/35864. Do you see a little number next to the recompile button? Anyway, it is possible that no LaTeX errors are reported. In that case you need to grab the `.blg` file (see my comments above) and have a look at that.

Comment: no I don't see a little number next to the recompile button

Comment: I downloaded the .blg file what should I do next?

Comment: But when I open the .blg file there is nothing inside

Comment: Open the `.blg` file with your favourite text editor and have a look at its contents. If you need help, paste the complete contents of the `.blg` file in the question. (If you are on Windows, Windows might classify the `.blg` file as a "performance monitor file" or some such, even though it is a simple text file you can open with any text editor.)

Comment: there is no content in the .blg file

Comment: Oh now I see I opened it with word!

Comment: What should be the next step?

Comment: Post the contents of the file here if they don't help you.

Comment: but what I am looking for in the content?

Comment: Well, if anything is wrong there should be an error message like `Too many commas in name 1 of "Anne Elk, Belk, Celk, Delk" for entry elk
while executing---line 1347 of file plainnat.bst` or ```I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 8 of file Namenlos-dsd79.bib
 :   
 :   year      = {1972},```.

Comment: I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 505 of file REFBIB.bib
 : @article{williams2007ostracism

Comment: it said what i just sent you

Comment: or this Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "lakin2005exclusion"

Comment: Please copy and paste the complete file contents into your question (you can edit your question). The messages are really hard to read without formatting in the comments.

Comment: I just added it

Comment: Do you see a solution?

Comment: You have several entries with the same key (at least two `erel2021excluded`s, `williams2009ostracism`s etc etc.). You need to make sure that each key is only used once.  `Illegal end of database file---line 1588 of file REFBIB.bib` also doesn't sound good: It suggests an entry around line 1588 (it may well be a few lines above) is very badly broken. It might be mismatched/missing curly braces or missing commas. Hard to say without having seen the relevant entry.

Comment: I see but the references that doesn't appear in the pdf  are not the one listed inn the problems here

Comment: It's hard to say from here when we only have those error messages. But those errors must be fixed. You cannot expect reasonable output from a file that produces errors like. Especially the last error `Illegal end of database file` means that BibTeX may abandon reading the file before it has actually ended. This may mean that entries you want to see are ignored.

Comment: I see but I have no more entries after the illegal end of database file

Comment: But I'm gonna fixe these issues and see if there is still the problems

Comment: Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "lakin2005exclusion" What does it mean?

Comment: It means pretty much what it says: You cited an entry called `lakin2005exclusion`, but BibTeX did not manage to find it. That does not necessarily mean it is not there. It can also mean that a previous entry has errors that force BIbTeX to abandon reading the file before it can encounter `lakin2005exclusion`. It's hard to say what exactly is the issue without having seen the `.bib` file, but I'd say the most likely cause of your error are missing or mismatched curly braces or possibly missing commas.

Comment: and this? Warning--empty journal in wortham2016does

Comment: Again, fairly self-explanatory: BibTeX expects `wortham2016does` to have a `journal` field, but there isn't one. Presumably `wortham2016does` is an `@article` entry, which should really have a `journal`. Either add the missing journal or choose a more appropriate entry type if there is no journal.