# Problem with .bib file while submission to arxiv from Overleaf

Tags: bibtex, arxiv, bbl

During submitting my paper in arxiv as a .zip file, they require the bibliography to be in .bbl format. However, I had prepared my latex using Overleaf that generated a .bib file. I followed [this TeX.SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462314/overleaf-v2-how-to-get-bbl-file) and generated the .zip file for arxiv submission (the answer by @imnothere). Now the .zip that is generated contains both a .bib and a .bbl file and I uploaded the paper in arxiv, but I got the error message that no .tex file is available.

I couldn't understand what to do. Should I remove the .bib file from the .zip file? Is there any problem due to the names of the files?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The submission to arxiv should contain your `.tex`, `images` and the `.bbl` file if relevant

Comment: LaTeX and BibTeX do *not* create the bib file. Instead, BibTeX creates the bbl file, and LaTeX reads the contents of the bbl file while typesetting the complete document.

Comment: Hello there, Tom from Overleaf support here. I see you mention that the ZIP file from our arXiv export/submit didn't work in arXiv. If you contact us at support@overleaf.com with both the ZIP file (unless it's super-large) and the URL of your project, we might be able to see what's going on wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

The .bbl file is what's created by BibTeX. When you're ready to submit your paper, you could either replace the instruction `\bibliography{<.bib file[s]>}` in your main tex file with the *contents* of the `\jobname.bbl` file, or replace `\bibliography{<.bib file[s]>}` with `\input{\jobname.bbl}`. Here, `\jobname` is the name of your main tex file. If you choose the latter method, be sure to include the .bbl file in the zip file you upload to arxiv.

Answer (score -1):

It is explained on the official overleaf website:

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/The_journal_says_%22don%27t_use_BibTeX%3B_paste_the_contents_of_the_.bbl_file_into_the_.tex_file%22._How_do_I_do_this_on_Overleaf%3F

Downloading files from the cache
Files created during compilation are stored in the project’s cache, including any .bbl files.

Follow these steps to download a file contained in the cache:

click the file icon (Accesslogs.png) beside the Recompile button;
scroll down and select Other logs and files;
a list of files in the cache is presented;
select output.bbl to download it.

Downloading the source, including the .bbl file
It’s also possible to download the source code with the .bbl included. Use the following steps to do that:

select Submit from the menu above the PDF preview window;
scroll down to Online Repositories;
locate arXiv;
select Submit your paper to the arXiv

within the pop-up window select Download project ZIP with submission files (e.g. .bbl)

extract the .bbl file from the downloaded ZIP file;
(see video) comment out the line \bibliography{...} within your .tex file on Overleaf, then paste the contents of the .bbl file.