# Overleaf: Citation X on page Y undefined on input line latex

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

In overleaf, I suddenly, I get the warnings "Citation X on page Y undefined on input line latex" - all my citations/bib-references are not found! I cannot solve the problem by exchanging the bib-file or reducing my big project. I had this issue a couple of hours ago, restarted overleaf and my computer, then deleted and re-added the line at the same place:

```
\addbibresource{220227BibTeXc.bib}
```

That worked, and it showed that it was not my fault but overleaf behaved weirdly. Now, restarting doesn't work; cleaning the overleaf cache did not help either. Do you have any advice, please? It's about my thesis which I need to hand in today!

This is my blg file:

```
[0] Config.pm:311> INFO - This is Biber 2.16
[0] Config.pm:314> INFO - Logfile is 'output.blg'
[119] biber:340> INFO - === Wed Mar  2, 2022, 18:49:39
[147] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'output.bcf'
[1362] Biber.pm:952> INFO - Found 469 citekeys in bib section 0
[1392] Biber.pm:4340> INFO - Processing section 0
[1405] Biber.pm:4531> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file '220227BibTeXc.bib' for section 0
[1592] bibtex.pm:1689> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[3539] bibtex.pm:1494> INFO - Found BibTeX data source '220227BibTeXc.bib'
[7583] Utils.pm:411> ERROR - Name "Berrisford, P, Dee, DP, Poli, P, Brugge, R, Fielding, M, Fuentes, M, K{å}llberg, PW, Kobayashi, S, Uppala, S, Simmons, A" has too many commas, skipping entry 'Berrisford2011-ir'
[7584] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry with key 'Berrisford2011-ir' in section '0' is cited and found but not created (likely due to sourcemap)
[10665] Utils.pm:411> ERROR - Name "H. Douville, K. Raghavan, J. Renwick, R. P. Allan, P. A. Arias, M. Barlow, R. Cerezo-Mota, A. Cherchi, T. Y. Gan, J. Gergis, D. Jiang, A. Khan, W. Pokam Mba, D. Rosenfeld, J. Tierney, O. Zolina" has too many commas, skipping entry 'Douville2021-fl'
[10666] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry with key 'Douville2021-fl' in section '0' is cited and found but not created (likely due to sourcemap)
[11299] Utils.pm:411> ERROR - Name "Jia, G., E. Shevliakova, P. Artaxo, N. De Noblet-Ducoudré, R. Houghton, J. House, K. Kitajima, C. Lennard, A. Popp, A. Sirin, R. Sukumar, L. Verchot" has too many commas, skipping entry 'Jia2019-er'
[11299] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry with key 'Jia2019-er' in section '0' is cited and found but not created (likely due to sourcemap)
[11601] Utils.pm:411> ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: /tmp/biber_tmp_8EtC/52685040a5aa4f7fc552b6f2d72ba1c7_29.utf8, line 9072, syntax error: found "year", expected end of entry ("}" or ")") (skipping to next "@")
[11601] Biber.pm:128> INFO - WARNINGS: 3
[11602] Biber.pm:132> INFO - ERRORS: 4
```

Comment: If this was working fine before, and it is indeed an Overleaf problem you are likely going to get faster and better help by contacting Overleaf support (who are very good).

Comment: Thanks! I've sent an email two hours ago.

Comment: Here's hoping you get quick help from Overleaf or somebody with relevant experience reads this! – My two cents: Creating a new user account on your computer, and then running Overleaf and your document there, would possibly amount to a fresh start. (On a Mac, this is a rather trivial procedure and would be worth a shot, don't know about your OS.) Good luck!

Comment: Would I download the whole project.zip and upload it under another user name? - I already tried copying the project, and also copying/pasting single files and texts into a new project. The former caused the same error, the latter caused other errors, even worse. - Is there a faster way how to contact Overleaf other than by email? I have even a paid version...

Comment: Of course it is possible that Overleaf is being weird, but in my experience the more likely explanation is an error in your document or `.bib` file. What exactly are the symptoms here? What errors do you get? Only the warning about empty bibliography/missing cites or additional messages? Do you get any errors or warnings from Biber? Download the `.blg` file as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864 (that post explains how to download the `.bbl`, you will have to get the `.blg`: the strategy is the same) and open it with a text editor. Tell us what it says.

Comment: All the `ERROR` and `WARN` messages refer to faulty entries. The name fields in `Berrisford2011-ir`, `Douville2021-fl` and `Jia2019-er` are malformed: Several names need to be separated with `and`, not with a comma. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864

Comment: Additionally there is a syntax error around line 9072 of your `.bib` file. It's probably a missing comma after a field value. But it could be something else. Check a few lines before 9072 and after closely. Fix all of these errors. Then clean the cache (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache) and recompile.

Comment: I've deleted Berrisford, Douville and Jia in my bib. This error remains: "/tmp/biber_tmp_24su/59e7cca01c9c1421586771b64a9242fa_13.utf8, line 9023, syntax error: found "year", expected end of entry ("}" or ")") (skipping to next "@")" - How do I find out which entry this is? Is that in my .bib file?

Comment: line 9023 looks like this (the one with "author"): @MISC{Simmons2021-ky,
  title     = "Low frequency variability and trends in surface air temperature
               and humidity from {ERA5} and other datasets",
  author    = "Simmons, Adrian and Hersbach, Hans and Munoz-Sabater, Joaquin
               and Nicolas, Julien and Vamborg, Freja and Berrisford, Paul and
               de Rosnay, Patricia and Willett, Kate and Woollen, Jack",
  publisher = "ECMWF",
  year      =  2021
}

Comment: The entry `Simmons2021-ky` you've shown does not have a syntax error. Clear the cache and rerun everything. Download the `.blg` file again and check which line it reports as problematic now. Check the entry above and below the one that is indicated as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone! I was just able to submit my thesis in time :-))