# Overleaf: Biblatex: I'm getting the error message "Empty bibliography"

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, overleaf

I've checked out the other answers to this apparently common question, but none work for me.

My use of Biblatex was working before, but now I get this error message. I've cleared the cache, but to no avail. I've added [backend=biber] but that didn't help either.

My code is like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\title{IIB Project: Roadmap to Zero Emissions in a Cambridge College}
\author{Candidate 5557G}

\begin{document}

\cite{PMSpeech}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In a file called References.bib:

```
@online{PMspeech,
  author = {UK Government},
  title = {Prime Minister's statement on coronavirus (COVID-19): 23 March 2020},
  year = "2020",
  url = {https://www.gov.uk/government/speeches/pm-address-to-the-nation-on-coronavirus-23-march-2020},
  urldate = {2022-05-25}
}
```

Comment: Then you need to prepare an example that generates that message. With what you have provided here we cannot recreate the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to this. I've updated now to include what I think should be sufficient code.

Comment: If you are having trouble with your bibliography, the `.blg` file is usually a very useful resource. It is the Biber log file and contains warnings and error messages about your `.bib` file. On Overleaf you can download the file as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864 for the `.bbl`. The `.blg` file is a simple text file that can be opened with any text editor (Windows might want to tell you that the `.blg` file is a performance monitor file and may not suggest you open it with a text editor - in this instance Windows is wrong).

Comment: Bro I wish you had added this as an answer instead of as a comment; you were totally right! The blg file was easy to read and explained that I had made a syntax error. Fixing this gave my references back ^.^

Answer (score 2):

When I run your example through `biber` I get (via TeXLive 2022)

```
Biber warning: [173] Biber.pm:130> WARN - Possible typo (case mismatch) between citation and datasource keys: 'PMSpeech' and 'PMspeech' in file 'file.bib' 
Biber warning: [173] Biber.pm:130> WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'PMSpeech' (section 0)
```

In your `.bib` file you define `PMspeech` (lower case `s`) but you cite `\cite{PMSpeech}`. Case matters.

Comment: As you can see comments are not for code, please add this as an addendum to your question, don't delete the rest, otherwise my answer makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The answer: I had made a syntax error in the References.bib file. This broke the whole thing.

Solution: Download the .blg file and read it in a text editor. I'm on a chromebook and use Simple. More help here:(tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864).

This file explained where my error was, and fixing it brought back the references. I had to run through this process a few times since I had made a few errors, but each .blg file only shows one of them.