# Undefined citation in overleaf

Tags: citing, natbib, overleaf

I'm trying to cite the following citation using `\citep{citation1]` but the ouptut shows a question mark instead of the citation.

> Package natbib Warning: Citation `citation1' on page 4 undefined on input line 3.

I'm pretty sure the citation in the .bib file is correct as I'm just copying and pasting them in overleaf.

```
@article{citation1,
  title={What do we know about audit quality?},
  author={Francis, Jere R},
  journal={The British accounting review},
  volume={36},
  number={4},
  pages={345--368},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

but the name Francis has a square around it for some reason and I'm guessing this is the problem.
[image]

Comment: `\citep{citation1]` should be `\citep{citation1}`, but I imagine that's a typo here.  Assuming you have no errors in the document, [download the blg file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462316/106162) and check that for errors.  This bib entry looks fine, and the highlighted `Fra` appears to simply be a text search match.